# How to apply my function to the first row of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, row

```
def calcScore(p):
   if p[0] > p[1]:
    x = 3
    y = 0
   elif p[0] == p[1]:
    x = 1
    y = 1
   else:
    x = 0
    y = 3

   return x,y
```

How would I apply this function to the first row of my dataframe?
I know how to apply it to the whole dataframe but can't seem to apply it to the first row only? Below is what I did with the whole dataframe. I am new to python so please forgive silly or stupid mistakes. Thank you. :)

```
  result =(prem[['FTHG','FTAG']].apply(calcScore, axis = 1))
  print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is for applying a function to all rows or columns. If you just want one you can just do:

```
result = calcScore(perm.iloc[0, ['FHG', 'FtAG']])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!